# Combine shell script and data files into one runnable script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a server that accepts HTTP POST request and runs the post data as a bash script (in a sandboxed environment).

E.g. at the client side I can do this:

```
~ $ curl http://my-server.com/sh -d "echo hello"
+ echo hello
hello
```

At the server side the post data is stored to a file and executed as a bash script. (In a sandboxed environment.)

I would like to use this functionality to compile small C++ projects. A project usually contains a couple of source and header files and an accompanying makefile or build script. An example build script would be:

```
g++ -c util.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ *.o
./a.out
```

How can I combine this script and the source files into a single file that I can use for the post request?

Comment: YOUR ENTIRE SERVER IS CURRENTLY OPEN TO THE PUBLIC.  I CAN RUN ANY COMMAND I WANT!

Comment: It's running in a sandboxed environment. Feel free to abuse it. If you notice security flaws, please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like you want the client to create a [shell archive](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shar).

Comment: Well, for one... I could fill up your whole harddrive with dd if=/dev/zero of=somefile count=<big number>

Comment: Your running Linux stacked-crooked 3.2.0-24-virtual #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 18:44:18 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: "I have a server that accepts HTTP POST request and runs the post data as a bash script." <prophecy>Not for long.</prophecy>

Comment: @twalberg Let me know if you discover a way to abuse it.

Comment: @Stephen yes, very good.

Comment: Edited the url to something private because everyone was distracted by the fact that everyone can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
curl http://stacked-crooked.com/sh -d 'echo H4sIABq0uFEAA+3VvW6DMBSG4cy+ihOyJFICx4TYQ6rOvQ0CJBBRXPHTWqp67zVFyUgn6I++ZzlCWLI9vGD9fDE1ZlZRRP3USn9NDofnQbgnGcqDkntWShJLqZgXxJOfzOmaNq7dUa6X2oytc8vO55H3w03oPv+IVVElZZdm9NC0aWH8/FH89JFgRtZPJt/j2/5d87f+dch9/wct0f8c7v171s898RwX1XpD7+Kla5u195SVpdnSm6nLdOltjuIDX4f/pe6qyffou9d6pP9I3/qXUkd9/zqM0P8cVsvgVFTBKW5y0WQt7bJXK8QlSWhnyJL7PQg/sKgeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOC3+wQXspMdACgAAA==  | base64 --decode | tar -xzv && ./run'
```

Comment: Dare I ask what `./run` does?

Comment: @chepner `./run` compiles the program using gcc and then runs it.

Comment: The nature of the encoded program is what intrigues me. I wouldn't recommend posting an answer that runs unknown, unexplained code.